# Why does "&" give me the memory address of some objects but not others?

Tags: go

This is the code in question (comment line "line in question" points to what I'm talking about): https://tour.golang.org/moretypes/20

Why does code like:

```
var a int
fmt.Println(&a)
```

Give me a memory address...but code like:

```
var m = map[string]Vertex{
    "Bell Labs": Vertex{
        40.68433, -74.39967,
    }
...
fmt.Println(&m)
```

Doesn't do that?

Is it the difference between the object types?

Comment: `&m` **allways** is the address of `m` so your question makes no sense at all as stated. The problem is that `fmt.Println` does a shitload of magic and behaves differently depending on what type of argument you pass. Takeaway: **Never** use fmt.Println to "debug" you code unless you know by heart what fmt.Println actually does.

Answer (score 5):

It can sometimes be difficult to say "why" something is a certain way, but this behavior is specified in [the documentation of the `fmt` package](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/). For whatever reason, the default format for a pointer to a simple object such as an integer is `%p` (the memory location in hex with a leading `0x`), while the default format for a pointer to a compound object such as a map is `&` plus the default format of the compound object.

But that's just the *default* format (`%v`), which is what `fmt.Println` produces. If you want to print the address of a map, you can switch to `fmt.Printf` (which lets you specify a custom format string), and use `%p` explicitly:

```
    fmt.Printf("%p\n", &m)
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is due to the way `fmt.Println` is written, specifically the `printValue` function in `print.go` at https://github.com/golang/go/blob/go1.14/src/fmt/print.go#L762

You can use `fmt.Printf("%p\n",m)` to ensure the address is printed.